# can the given idiom be used this way?

Tags: grammaticality, idioms

If you like the video and want to see **more where this came from**, subscribe to the channel.

Is this sentence grammatically accurate, and does it mean "If you like this video and want to see more videos alike/more such videos, subscribe to the channel."?

Comment: Stylistically, I would prefer: "If you **liked this** video and want to see more **like it**, subscribe to **this** channel." Although understandable, the idiom is not normally used in the way you used it. Instead, *there are more where that came from* is the set phrase—with variations for different pronouns.

Comment: "More where this came from" would mean more from the same source (i.e. you, if it's your video channel), rather than "more like this". Though it would probably be assumed that new videos from the same channel would be like the original one

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is grammatical and correct.

I would say that "more where this came from" has quite an informal and potentially playful tone.  If your channel is serious or at all formal, I would not use this expression.